# In NX build, is there a way to get project name in package.json?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, package.json, monorepo

I am having a Monorepo and using NX build system.

I am trying to figure out a way to inject the project name in my package.json

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "sampleCmd": "env-cmd -f apps/${projectName}/.env.local"
  },
```

I am looking for a way to inject the projectName/appName.

Example:

If I execute `yarn sampleCmd user-service`

The sampleCmd should be `"env-cmd -f apps/user-service/.env.local"`

Answer (score 0):

Yarn `run` command [just add arguments to end of script](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/#toc-yarn-run-script) command defined in `package.json`. It's not possible to get a specific argument, neither to change the order.

But as a workaround, we can create a dedicated script in a `scripts` folder for example, and reference it from `package.json`.
Then inside this script, we can get arguments.

for example, in `/scripts/sample-cmd.sh`

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd $(dirname ${0})/..
PROJECT_NAME="${1}"

env-cmd -f apps/$PROJECT_NAME/.env.local
```

Then in `package.json` :

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "sampleCmd": "./scripts/sample-cmd.sh"
},
```

Of course, this need to be adapted to target environment, system... (bash, linux/mac/windows...). But the main idea is here.

Note this in not related to NX monorepo, and will work for every NPM/YARN project.